# Job 28:9 mountains' roots?

Tags: hebrew, job, cosmology

> Job 28:9: They put their hand to the flinty rock, and overturn mountains by the roots "miš-šō-reš"

Did Job in 28:9 believe that part of the mountains is rooted in the earth?

Comment: There are two guys in a bar, and the first says "inability to recognize metaphor is a real handicap", and the second one gets mad, saying "Are you accusing me of being disabled!?"

Answer (score 1):

Job 28:

> 9 People assault the flinty rock with their hands
> and lay bare the roots of the mountains.

Job compared mountains to trees. These people were miners digging to the depths, looking for ores.

Pulpit:

> He overturneth the mountains by the roots. Herodotus, in describing what he had seen of the Phoenician **mining** operations in the island of Thasos, observes, "a huge, mountain has been turned upside down in the search for ores" (Herod., 6:47). Pliny says of the process employed for detaching huge masses from the metalliferous hills in Spain, "They **attack** the rock with iron wedges and hammers. When this work is complete, they destroy the supports, and notify by signal that the fall is about to take place. A watchman, stationed on the mountain-top, alone understands the signal; and he proceeds at once to have all the workmen called in, and himself makes a hurried retreat. Then the mountain falls upon itself with a crash that cannot be imagined, and an incredible concussion of the air. The successful engineers contemplate the ruin which they have achieved" ('Hist. Nat.,' 33:4. § 73).

The description is like felling a tree.

Did Job in 28:9 believe that part of the mountains is rooted in the earth?

Yes in the metaphorical sense.

Comment: thanx Tony... if the The description of the writer of Job is like the process of felling a tree ,then it seems ,he was talking LITERALLY ,and he did believe that mountains have roots under earth(which is true scientifically) ,just like trees have roots under earth.. don't you think so?

Comment: What is the scientific definition of a root of a mountain? Please cite a link :)

Comment: did  Pliny  or other christians in the past ,believe that mountains have roots deep inside earth?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/how-much-of-a-mountain-is-below-the-surface    a root of a mountain?

Comment: If you accept this as a scientific definition of a mountain root, then Job 28:9 is iteral.

Answer (score 0):

**Job 28:9 mountains' roots?**

The answer is no: rather, Job is contrasting the natural resources of the earth [Vs1-11} with  Godly wisdom. [Vs 12-28]

Read  Job 28

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job28&version=NASB,NET,ASV

**Job Tells of Earth’s Treasures [Vs1-11]**

Man has made tremendous progress by studying nature, in mining, food growth, exploring the depths of the sea, the skies, and so on,  all this is vain when  Godly wisdom and purpose are not considered.

1 Corinthians 1:19-20 NET

> 19 For it is written, “I will destroy the wisdom of the wise, and I
> will thwart the cleverness of the intelligent.”[a] 20 Where is the
> wise man? Where is the expert in Mosaic law?[b] Where is the debater
> of this age? Has God not made the wisdom of the world foolish?

**Job’s Search for Wisdom (28:12-28]**

No matter how much men exploit and study the earth and nature, they can never by their own efforts find wisdom that leads to righteousness and happiness.  Such understanding is more precious than gold, and the transient search for worldly riches and honor can bring.

And finally, Job says [Vs 28]  And to mankind He said, ‘Behold, the fear of the Lord, that is wisdom; And to turn away from evil is understanding.’”

To fear the Lord is to come to know God's personality, and this wisdom can only be gained by studying his Word- the Bible.